# how to get correct date with NestJs, Typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm attempting to retrieve category information from Postgress' database, and I have the proper creation timezone there. '2023-03-21 20:23:29.519129' at column, but when I try to obtain all categories I get another date:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "კომპიუტერები",
        "parentId": null,
        "createdAt": "2023-03-21T16:23:29.519Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-03-21T16:23:29.519Z"
}
```

like that, how can I fix? I want to obtain accurate global date information, not ToString() and the same variables.

Answer (score 1):

it's best to store the datetime without timezone (UTC) as following:

```
@CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' })
  createdAt: Date;
```

and set "process.env.TZ = 'Etc/Universal'" in your main.ts
and in your backend you retrive this dates in UTC 0 offset,
then frontend can convert the date to the local timezone

I think this is the best practise regarding timezones